# Understanding the (complex) GNU Radio implementation of Mueller & Muller

Tags: digital-communications, gnuradio, synchronization, symbol-timing

I have some questions about the M&M [implementation](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/main/gr-digital/lib/clock_recovery_mm_cc_impl.cc) of GNU Radio that uses complex samples.

I started reading the [implementation](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/main/gr-digital/lib/clock_recovery_mm_ff_impl.cc) for real values:

```
    while (oo < noutput_items && ii < ni) {
    // produce output sample
    out[oo] = d_interp.interpolate(&in[ii], d_mu);
    mm_val = slice(d_last_sample) * out[oo] - slice(out[oo]) * d_last_sample;
    d_last_sample = out[oo];

    d_omega = d_omega + d_gain_omega * mm_val;
    d_omega = d_omega_mid + gr::branchless_clip(d_omega - d_omega_mid, d_omega_lim);
    d_mu = d_mu + d_omega + d_gain_mu * mm_val;

    ii += (int)floor(d_mu);
    d_mu = d_mu - floor(d_mu);
    oo++;
}
```

I understand that after samples interpolation, the error term `mm_val`  is estimated as defined [here](https://wirelesspi.com/mueller-and-muller-timing-synchronization-algorithm/), using both the current and the previous symbol.
$$r_p(+T_M - \epsilon_\Delta) - r_p(-T_M - \epsilon_\Delta)$$

There, a simple slicer is used, to check if the current sample is closer to 1 or to -1:

```
float slice(float x) { return x < 0 ? -1.0F : 1.0F; }
```

Then, I tried to understand the complex version:

```
 while (oo < noutput_items && ii < ni) {
        d_p_2T = d_p_1T;
        d_p_1T = d_p_0T;
        d_p_0T = d_interp.interpolate(&in[ii], d_mu);

        d_c_2T = d_c_1T;
        d_c_1T = d_c_0T;
        d_c_0T = slicer_0deg(d_p_0T);

        fast_cc_multiply(x, d_c_0T - d_c_2T, conj(d_p_1T));
        fast_cc_multiply(y, d_p_0T - d_p_2T, conj(d_c_1T));
        u = y - x;
        mm_val = u.real();
        out[oo++] = d_p_0T;

        // limit mm_val
        mm_val = gr::branchless_clip(mm_val, 1.0);

        d_omega = d_omega + d_gain_omega * mm_val;
        d_omega =
            d_omega_mid + gr::branchless_clip(d_omega - d_omega_mid, d_omega_lim);

        d_mu = d_mu + d_omega + d_gain_mu * mm_val;
        ii += (int)floor(d_mu);
        d_mu -= floor(d_mu);

        if (d_verbose) {
            d_logger->info("{:.8f}\t{:.8f}", d_omega, d_mu);
        }

        if (ii < 0) // clamp it.  This should only happen with bogus input
            ii = 0;
    }
```

Here, some additional complex values are defined `(d_p_2T, d_p_1T, d_p_0T, d_c_2T, d_c_1T, d_c_0T)`.

1. I understand it has to do with the symbols that arrived 1 and 2
   symbol periods before. Is this right?
2. If so, why do we need them in the complex implementation but we do not in the real number implementation?
3. What's the meaning of the two sets of complex numbers d_p and d_c?
4. Also, I'm a bit confused about the [implementation](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/main/gr-digital/lib/clock_recovery_mm_cc_impl.h) of the slicer. Why is it called 0deg slicer? Why is it returning for I and Q only 0.0f and 1.0f and not -1.0f and 1.0f like in the real case?

   ```
    gr_complex slicer_0deg(gr_complex sample)
    {
        float real = 0.0f, imag = 0.0f;

        if (sample.real() > 0.0f)
            real = 1.0f;
        if (sample.imag() > 0.0f)
            imag = 1.0f;
        return gr_complex(real, imag);
    }
   ```
5. Finally, I would like to grasp the idea of these conjugate multiplications. Why there are two branches `x` and `y`? Also, what is the idea of the conjugate multiplication? I've read [here](https://wirelesspi.com/mueller-and-muller-timing-synchronization-algorithm/) that `since the M&M TED does not involve any cancellation of phase through a conjugate product, it is not carrier independent and thus more suitable for timing synchronization after the settling of carrier loops in a steady state tracking mode`. Is it related to that?:

   ```
    fast_cc_multiply(x, d_c_0T - d_c_2T, conj(d_p_1T));
    fast_cc_multiply(y, d_p_0T - d_p_2T, conj(d_c_1T));
   ```

I must mention that I am trying to understand this from a BPSK demodulation perspective. Maybe this implementation is meant to also work with higher order/other modulations schemes and that's why I am not grasping the idea of what is being computed here? I'm sorry for long explanation but I cannot find info anywhere.

Comment: The M&M blocks in GNURadio have some terrible bugs.  The complex version slicer is just one of the bad bugs.  Forget it and use the Symbol Sync block and select the M&M TED

Comment: See slides 31 and 32 of this: https://www.gnuradio.org/grcon/grcon17/presentations/symbol_clock_recovery_and_improved_symbol_synchronization_blocks/

Comment: @AndyWalls Thank you! I guess [here](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/main/gr-digital/lib/timing_error_detector.cc) the error term is computed. If I am right, the difference between plain and modified M&M is the use of conjugate product as well as using 2 or 3 symbols ([0] and [1] or [0], [1] and [2]), respectively. Is there any documentation/book about this? The [link](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Clock_Recovery_MM) to implementation notes in the description is broken. Also can't find the paper in open access or IEEExplore :( Maybe you know where I can learn about this?